# How can I remove all files by pattern from bash with except for specific files?

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, terminal

I try to automatically remove all files from directory but exclude the specific files

The syntax `$ rm *.!(vmx*|vmd*)` works good if I run it from terminal, but if I create some bash script file (for example named: `patt1_exclude_vm_gb.sh` or `patt1_exclude_vm_gb`) it doesn't work.

```
-- patt1_exclude_vm_gb.sh
#!/bin/bash

$ rm *.!(vmx*|vmd*)
```

Does someone know how to correct the bash script ?

Comment: I think this can solve your problem: `shopt -s extglob`. That line goes before `rm` in your shell script

Comment: Thank You, it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `bash` you need to enable extended glob pattern support with `shopt -s extglob` before you can use the `!( ... )` pattern.  (or the other extended patterns `?( ... )`, `*( ... )`, `+( ... )`, and `@( ... )`)

Comment: Thanks, It works.